# Finding a pattern in a datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, datagridview

So I created a datagrid view with columns that go one through ten and rows that go 1 through 5 incremented .0 1. What I want to be able to do is accept 5 user given inputs and then search the grid and if those 5 inputs are in the same row in any row, highlight that row. I'm just not sure how to get started. A point in the right direction would be great.

Comment: You start by deciding how you want the user to interact with the program. One simple option is to use one textbox, tryparse the Lines and put the numbers in a List<int>. Then you can do the checks in a loop over the 5 rows..

Comment: I have set up a small form window where I have 5 text boxes and a button where they will enter the 5 different numbers and then press the button the find the row. I was possibly thinking about have each box cycle through the data grid and store all the row in which that number appears and then do the same with the other four and then highlight the row in which all 5 appear at the same time. Or does that sound a little to overly complicated?

Comment: That would be one way. The other is to cycle the rows and their cells and check each number. Whenever one is missing a number you can break and go to the next row. Probably a little bit faster.. Once you are through the loop the row is ok and can be highlighted. Then continune the outer loop to find more ok rows..